# XSD 2 elements once, 1 element 1+ any order

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation, complextype

I am working on an XML Schema that includes 3 elements which can be in **any order**.

- Two of them have to appear **exactly once**,
- The third element can appear **once** or **more than once**.
- All three are required.

In the example below, every bio has ONE `favoriteColor` and ONE `favoriteNumber`, and AT LEAST ONE `comment`.  I would LIKE them to be allowed in any order, (including alternating).

```
<xs:element name="bio">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="favoriteColor" maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1"/>
            <xs:element name="favoriteNumber" maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1"/>
            <xs:element name="comment" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="1"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

Once possible option is `<xs:choice>`, but it allows only ONE of the options.  It seems unwieldy to list every possible order combination as an alternate sequence: (abc, acb, bac, bca, cab, cba)... and it still doesn't account for the possibility of having comments interspersed between the other two. (e.g. "comment, number, comment, color, comment, comment" should be allowed)

`<xs:all>` would work well, except it only allows a maximum of 1 instance of each.  I need to allow multiple "comment"s.  I could put `<xs:element name="comment" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0"/>` both above and below an "all" tag, but that doesn't work.  See below:

```
<xs:element name="bio">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element ref="comment" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0"/>
            <xs:all> <!-- not allowed here -->
                <xs:element ref="favoriteColor" maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1"/>
                <xs:element ref="favoriteNumber" maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1"/>
                <xs:element ref="comment" maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1"/>
            </xs:all>
            <xs:element ref="comment" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

Any suggestions?  There are quite a few questions on this board that pertain to the order of elements in a schema, but I couldn't find any that addressed what I am trying to do (where I have a combination of "only once" and "at least once)."

Comment: I don't think possible. Even <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element ref="comment" maxOccurs="unbounded"
     minOccurs="0" />

    <xs:element ref="comment" maxOccurs="unbounded"
     minOccurs="0" />
   </xs:sequence> will give you error. (cos-nonambig: "http://test":comment and "http://test":comment (or elements from their substitution group) violate "Unique Particle 
 Attribution". During validation against this schema, ambiguity would be created for those two particles.)

Comment: @sashwat, Can you post that as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think possible. Even

```
<xs:sequence>
     <xs:element ref="comment" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" /> 
     <xs:element ref="comment" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" />
</xs:sequence>
```

will give you error. (cos-nonambig: "test":comment and "test":comment (or elements from their substitution group) violate "Unique Particle Attribution". During validation against this schema, ambiguity would be created for those two particles.)